# Inverse function of $x \mapsto \coth x - 1/x$

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-functions, elementary-functions

Consider the function $f$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) = \coth x - \frac{1}{x}$$
if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Since the function $\coth$ can be developed in series as $\coth x = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^3}{45} + \cdots$ around the origin, the function $f$ can easily be shown to be infinitely smooth over $\mathbb{R}$, strictly increasing, with limits $\pm 1$ in $\pm \infty$. The function $f$ is therefore a smooth bijection from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (-1,1)$.

My question is the following: Is there an analytic expression for the inverse $f^{-1} : (-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ such that $f^{-1}(y) = x$ if and only if $f(x) = y$?

Context: The function $f$ naturally appears in an optimization problem I am considering. It would be useful for me to understand and possibly compute what the inverse is.

Comment: Intuition would suggest, probably not, unfortunately. Using the exponential form of $\coth$, you have that $x$ solves $\left(\left(1-y\right)x-1\right)e^{2x}+\left(y+1\right)x+1=0$ given $y$. Mixed polynomials in $x, e^x$ don't generally have elementary analytic solutions.

Comment: You want the inverse of the [Langevin function](https://www.accessscience.com/content/article/a370300). There is a [series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01555) for the inverse

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and refs. The wikipedia page on the Langevin function also provides interesting aspects, discussing about the inverse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_and_Langevin_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “Langevin function” is invertible via [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lagrange%20reversion,of%20compositions%20with%20such%20functions.&text=Then%20for%20any%20function%20g%2C%20for%20small%20enough%20y%3A&text=In%20which%20case%20the%20equation%20can%20be%20derived%20using%20perturbation%20theory.):

$$L(x)=\coth(x)-\frac1x=a\mathop\iff^{x=\frac{y-1}{a+1}} y=e^\frac{2(y-1)}{a+1} \left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}(y-1)+1\right)\implies x=\frac1{a+1}\left(-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{2n}{a+1}}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^\frac{2nt}{a+1}\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}(t-1)+1\right)^n\right|_0\right)$$

Using [general Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule):

$$\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^\frac{2nt}{a+1}\left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}(t-1)+1\right)^n\right|_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}e^\frac{2n t}{a+1}\right|_0 \left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}} \left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}(t-1)+1\right)^n\right|_0$$

and [summing over $k$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28e%5E%28-2%2F%281%2B%28x%29%29%29%29%5En%2Fn%21+binom%28n-1%2Ck%29+2%5E%28-k%2Bn-1%29+n%5E%28-k%2Bn-1%29+%28x+%2B+1%29%5E%28k+-+n+%2B+1%29+%282%5E%28-k+%2B+n%29+%281%2F%281%2B%28x%29%29%29%5E%28-k%2Bn%29+%28%28-1%2B%28x%29%29%2F%281%2B%28x%29%29%29%5Ek+n%21%29%2F%28n-k%29%21%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D) uses [hypergeometric $\operatorname U(a,b,x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hypergeometric+U). Therefore:

$$\bbox[2px, border: 2px solid silver]{L^{-1}(x)=-\frac1{x+1}\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{n-1}}{e^\frac{2n}{x+1}(x+1)^nn!}\operatorname U\left(1-n,2,-\frac{4n}{x^2-1}\right)\right)}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coth%28y%29-1%2Fy%2Cy%3Dlim%5B-1%2F%28x%2B1%29+%281%2Bsum%5B%282+%28-1%29%5En+e%5E%28-%282+n%29%2F%281+%2B+x%29%29+%28-1+%2B+x%29%5E%28-1+%2B+n%29+%281+%2B+x%29%5E%28-n%29+U%281+-+n%2C+2%2C+-%284+n%29%2F%28-1+%2B+x%5E2%29%29%29%2F%28n%21%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%29%2Cx-%3E-0.7%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Bcoth%28y%29+-+1%2Fy%2C+y+%3D+-3.30354%7D). The series converges more quickly as $x\to-1$ and symmetry extends the convergence radius to $x>0$

Comment: [Additional series expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coth%28x%29-1%2Fx%2Cx%3D1%2F%281-0.4%29-2+sum%5B%28%28%281+%2B+0.4%29%2F%28-1+%2B+0.4%29%29%5En+E%5E%28%282+n%29%2F%28-1+%2B+0.4%29%29+%28n-1%29%21+LaguerreL%5B-1+%2B+n%2C+1%2C+%284+n%29%2F%281-+0.4%5E2%29%5D%29%2F%28%28-1+%2B+0.4%5E2%29+Pochhammer%5B2%2C+-1+%2B+n%5D%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D) with [this $L^1_{n-1}(x)$ integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5B%28e%5E%28i+t+-+e%5E%28i+t%29+x%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28-i+t%29%29%5En%29%2F%282+π%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2π%7D%5D). Maybe one can find an $\int$ result

Comment: Using the above for $L^{-1}(0.4)$, you get [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%281-0.4%29-2+Nintegrate%5Bsum%5B%28-1.19048+%28-2.33333%29%5En+%28-1+%2B+n%29%21%29%2F%28E%5E%283.33333+n%29+Pochhammer%5B2%2C+-1+%2B+n%5D%29+%28e%5E%28i+t+-+e%5E%28i+t%29+%284n%2F%281-0.4%5E2%29%29%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28-i+t%29%29%5En%29%2F%282+π%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2π%7D%5D),

Comment: but evaluating the sum symbolically using WolframAlpha and then numerically [fails](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%281-0.4%29-2+Nintegrate%5B0.189471+e%5E%28i+t%29+log%280.0356741+2.71828%5E%28-4.7619+2.71828%5E%28i+t%29+-+i+t%29+%282.33333+%2B+28.0315+2.71828%5E%284.7619+2.71828%5E%28i+t%29+%2B+i+t%29+%2B+2.33333+2.71828%5E%28i+t%29%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C2π%7D%5D)

Answer (score 2):

Use th [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem):
if $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$$ with $a_1 \neq 0$
(interpreted either as an analytic function or as a formal power series),
then
\begin{equation}
   f^{-1}(w)  \;=\;
   \sum_{m=1}^\infty {w^m \over m} \,
      [\zeta^{m-1}] \biggl( {\zeta \over f(\zeta)}\biggr)^m
   \;,
\end{equation}
where $[\zeta^n] g(\zeta) = g^{(n)}(0)/n!$ denotes the coefficient of $\zeta^n$
in the power series $g(\zeta)$.
More generally, if $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$, we have
\begin{equation}
   h(f^{-1}(w))  \;=\;
   h(0) \,+\,
   \sum_{m=1}^\infty {w^m \over m} \,
      [\zeta^{m-1}] \, h'(\zeta) \biggl( {\zeta \over f(\zeta)}\biggr)^m
   \;.
\end{equation}
Proofs of these formulae can be found in many books on analytic function
theory.

Comment: Thanks. This allows to obtain the Taylor coefficients.